# Excel VBA code to replace string in range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add code that will search for the string #DIV/0! in a range of cells (EF:W10) and if found, will replace that cell with NA.  Below is what I have, but it is not quite working.  What am I missing?

```
Dim rngDiv As Range
For Each rngDiv In Range("E4:W10")
    If InStr(rngDiv.Value, "#DIV/0!") > 0 Then
        rngDiv.Value = "NA"
    End If
Next rngDiv
```

Comment: Instead of using a sledgehammer to kill a fly, why don't you change the formula in those cells to `=IFERROR([current formula],"NA")` ?

Comment: agree with @MacroMan!

Comment: No can do.  The entire code needs to be in the script so that it can be run on a blank new excel sheet.

Comment: But then the script must be adding the formula to your cells at some point. Make the script add macromans formula instead of the current one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need VBA to do this then you can use the `IsError()` function

```
Dim rngDiv As Range
For Each rngDiv In Range("E4:W10")
    If IsError(rngDiv) Then
        rngDiv.Value = "NA"
    End If
Next
```

However it's best to catch your errors in the actual formula rather than afterwards with VBA.

---

**Note:** The above will catch **all** errors - if you just want the `#DIV/0!` error then you need to test for the `.Text` property instead of the `.Value` property:

```
Dim rngDiv As Range
For Each rngDiv In Range("E4:W10")
    If rngDiv.Text = "#DIV/0!" Then
        rngDiv.Value = "NA"
    End If
Next rngDiv
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim rngDiv As Range
    For Each rngDiv In Range("E4:W10")
        If rngDiv.Text = "#DIV/0!" Then
            rngDiv.Value = "NA"
        End If
    Next rngDiv
End Sub
```

Comment: Strangely enough - I was actually going to link to [an old post of yours...](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/703597-xl2003-visual-basic-applications-replacing-div-0-error-string.html#post3474780)